# Can I merge 2 similar, but non tracked repositories in Git?

Tags: git, merge, branching-and-merging

I have a mainline repository which I want to merge my new features into. These features were developed on a copy of this repo. The way this repo was created was by simply doing a git init and dropping a copy of everything in there (ie: no history from the mainline is there, the first commit is just a straight copy of everything). I know that I can bring the feature repo into the mainline repo as a new branch BUT... I seem to just get `both added` conflicts for any files that have changes in both. Also, I am not sure if my history will be brought over from the feature repository, into the mainline repository? Will it just be seen as a single, large commit? Is there a way to do this the kosher way despite my previous mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have made commits on the "mainline" repo since you started working on the "new features" repo. If this be the case, you will need to create a branch in the mainline repo **from the commit that started the new repo**, not the current commit.

```
---o---o---o  mainline
    \
     o---o---o  new features
```

something like

```
cd mainline
git checkout -b new-features <origin commit for new features>
git remote add new-features ../new-features
```

From there should you be able to `git rebase` / `git merge` / `git cherry-pick` to your liking. Also going forward, don't do what you did. If you want to "branch" then use `git branch`.

Comment: So create a new branch in the mainline repo which refers to an intermittent commit. That commit being where the sloppy branch was created from. (The mainline repo will have a new branch, which points to that intermittent commit). Then create a third branch which contains the new features, rebase that onto the intermittent mainline branch, and finally merge the rebased branch back to mainline? Whew! Gonna need a Redbull for this one!